# What's the etiquette on remaking old puzzles?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

So recently I posted [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125962/a-simple-and-quite-fun-cipher-revisited) puzzle, which was a puzzle meant to give the intended solution to my first puzzle, which I had posted just over 5 months ago.

[Currently](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/revision/1825676/2219443/my-unanswered-questions), not counting my first puzzle<sup>note 1</sup> or questions with the [puzzle-creation] tag, I have 6 unanswered puzzles.

I have been wondering since I posted it whether or not to remake another old puzzle of mine that also has not been solved in 5 months.

However, I don't exactly know if there is any etiquette that I would need to follow when recreating old puzzles that still haven't been solved, or if it is generally unacceptable to do so.

So, my question is:

> Is it generally unacceptable to recreate old puzzles regardless of age?
> If it is acceptable in general, how old should they be to be eligible for recreation, and what else would have to be kept in mind during the recreation process?

---

<sup><sup>note 1</sup>As it is solved (due to the "revisited" version), it's just not counted as solved as I haven't accepted an answer yet.</sup>